# concat string var in razor var name

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I can't find anything to solve my problem in search, and here is my problem:

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 and EF 5, I'm trying to get a value from my db, but this db field depends on other var.

In Controller:

```
public ActionResult Products()
    {
        ViewBag.lang = "ENG";

        DataEntities db = new DataEntities();

        ViewBag.Categories = db.Categories;

        return View();
    }
```

In Template View:

```
<ul>
@{
    if (ViewBag.Categories != null)
    {
        foreach (var cat in ViewBag.Categories ) 
        {
            <!-- we need in this case "Name_ENG" -->
            var title = "Name_" + @ViewBag.lang;

            <li>@cat.(title)</li>
            <!-- out: cat.ToString() + "(title)" -->

            <li>@cat.(@title)</li>
            <!-- out: cat.ToString() + "(" + title.ToString() + ")" -->

            <li>@cat.@title</li>
            <!-- out: cat.ToString() +  title.ToString()  -->
        }
    }
}
</ul>
```

is there a way to get property "Name_ENG" from cat object like @cat.Name_ENG using a string ?

"In this case I'm trying to list al Categories in Products page."

Thanks a lot

Comment: I think we can't do this in way. what are the properties do you have in Categories entity?

Comment: probably I need to generate a custom collection in controller and pass it using ViewBag...

Comment: @garrigueta I am thinking that passing the categories details in a model to `View(model)` gives you better options, rather than using ViewBag. Then you can take advantage of helper methods such as [`Html.Display(title)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee310174(v=vs.118).aspx) to do what you want to do.

Comment: @Rhumborl I will use this functionality with Products, maybe I need to take a look at use of multiple models in one view like View(model1,model2), but I don't know if it's possible in easy way,  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, definitely not in c#. You'd have to use reflection for this to work (and the syntax would be different of course as well).

I think a better option would be to create a method that would retrieve the value based on a string input, like

```
public T GetValue<T>(string propertyName)
```

and call that from your view when needed

Comment: Is easyest way to use reflection or switch/case with @ViewBag.lang?, it has only 3 possible values.

Comment: @garrigueta, all approaches have their pros and cons. I'd suggest you to try both and see what suits the best your current situation and needs. Honestly, there are more ways of accomplishing this and it's kinda too broad for discussing it all here. Also, you can combine multiple approaches, so it's really just up to you (for instance you can combine method GetValue with reflection...)

Answer (score 0):

here is an article from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592677.aspx). You can access EF entries properties by name. But at first you need dbContext and second it is wrong to access dbContext from view.

example:

```
object currentName2 = context.Entry(blog).Property("Name").CurrentValue;
```

Also, as mentioned in another answer, reflection:

```
object value = typeof(YourType).GetProperty("PropertyName").GetValue(yourInstance, null);
```

Comment: It's great to know, I can fill custom array in this way without using ViewBag.lang and then send it to view. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<ul>
@{
    if (ViewBag.Categories != null)
    {
        foreach (var cat in ViewBag.Categories ) 
        {            
            // here you can do something on cat
            <text>
            <li>@(cat.title)</li>
            </text>
        }
    }
}
</ul>
```

I personally suggest you to pass the data to the view by parameter. And use @model in the view (strong type view).